# Android: Relative layout with multiple TextViews. What kind of adapter should I to bind data?

Tags: android, android-layout

Note: I am not using a ListView, so I thought ArrayAdapter is not really suitable.  I have a RelativeLayout with a TextView for Title and another TextView inside ScrollView for Description.

I want to fetch data from a webservice and display Title and Description in this view. What kind of Adapter should I use?

Binding to a ArrayAdapter seems not suitable. And CursorAdapter is not suitable too as I do not get the data from any database. I will be doing an AsyncTask to the the data from web service. And I want to bind the data to title and definition ids in my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/definition" />
    </ScrollView>

    <SearchView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to parse the data and set text to `TextView` using `setText("your text");`.

Comment: Adapters work with classes that inherit AdapterView. RelativeLayout doesn't. Just do it manually, why would you need an adapter for such a simple task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why adapter? Adapter -adapts- an interface to a collection to an interface required by that collection's viewer. You seem not to have such a Viewer.

Comment: I had not understood Adapters in android well. I went ahead with directly updating the views.